# Is it possible to make a command stop after the first line of *output*?

Tags: windows-10, command-line

I've got this command:

```
wevtutil qe System /rd /f:Text | findstr "4800 4801"
```

It takes a very long time to finish, even though I'm only interested in the very first line of output.

I know that `wevutil` has a `/c:1` flag, but if I use that, such as:

```
wevtutil qe System /rd /f:Text /c:1 | findstr "4800 4801"
```

Then nothing is outputted.

The reason for this is that the `/c:1` flag says to return only one row, but the `findstr` command is applied afterwards, which filters out the relevant event codes. Thus, unless by sheer chance one of those event codes happen to be the latest event, there will be empty output.

How can I apply the `/c:1` after the event filtering has been applied, so that I guarantee that only those events are displayed (never nothing)?

That is, I don't want to limit the number of rows that the `wevtutil` command fetches -- I want to limit the number of rows that my command ends up *outputting*. It takes many seconds every time I run this command, and I need it to be near-instant. It would probably be near-instant if it stopped after the first (relevant) record.

As far as I can tell, `webtutil` itself has no ability to "findstr", which is why the person who helped me figure out this command pipes the output to `findstr`...

Comment: Would doing this in Powershell using `get-eventlog` be acceptable?

Comment: @spikey_richie Sadly, no. There are some serious issues with PowerShell in my context which are hard to summarize.

Comment: What's the actual thing you're trying to filter? It seems like `/q` should be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the /c: flag correctly. That is the amount of **Events** to show, not lines.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/wevtutil#options

would the /k flag work? it is used for filtering the log as explained in the above link.

Comment: There is also the `/q` param for an XPath query. This would probably replace the need to pipe to `findstr` (?)

Comment: `wevtutil qe /?` says nothing about any `/k` flag. What do you mean?

Comment: Hmm. Odd. It does mention it on the webpage you linked to, but not in the command help...

Comment: I get `Invalid option k. Option is not supported.` when trying to use `/k`...

Comment: Hmm... I don't know what's wrong let me investigate

Comment: @mrnoob Did you give up? I get completely wrong timestamps returned by this command. It doesn't match whatsoever. It's completely broken, like everything seems to be in Windows (and all other OSes). I truly hate computers.

Comment: Looks like the documentation is for windows server. and no I did not give up, but yesterday I was really busy with fifth grade schoolwork. Try reading the help page or docs if you can find something.

Comment: try this command in powershell:
`wevtutil qe System /rd /f:Text | findstr "4800 4801" | select -first 1`
The only issue is that it still runs through the command, but only displays the first line